# What does $ function means in vanilla (no libraries) JS?

Tags: javascript, dollar-sign

I was wondering what does $ sign function means.

Is it just a shortcut to `document.querySelector` or does it have more uses.

I went to about:blank page and typed in console $.

Result in Firefox was:

`function()`

and in Chrome:

> ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }

It works as shortcut to `document.querySelector()` but I am not sure what it's called and what is browser support for this.

There is also $$ function that works as `document.querySelectorAll()`,

`$_` that stores last $/$$ function result,

`$0` that is just reference to `document.body` (I think)

and `$x` that i assume is XPath query becuase of xpath argument:

> ƒ $x(xpath, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }

(chrome output when typing `$x` in console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the "[Command Line API]" message suggests, it's a convenience function built into the browser, rather than a part of vanilla javascript.

For Chrome, for example:

> The Console Utilities API contains a collection of convenience functions for performing common tasks: selecting and inspecting DOM elements, displaying data in readable format, stopping and starting the profiler, and monitoring DOM events.
>   https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

Safari and Firefox appear to support the same set of functions as Chrome; I believe (but am not certain) that this is by consensus rather than an actual standard.

These functions will only work in the developer console; they are not usable  elsewhere.

```js
console.log($) // will throw "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $"
```

The `$` character itself has no special significance in javascript, and can be used as any other character glyph:

```js
var $ = "hello"
var a$b = "world"
console.log($, a$b)

$ = function() {console.log("This will confuse jQuery users, probably not a great idea")}
$()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have found the non-standardized identifiers built into each browser's developer tools. They are not part of vanilla JS.

- [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities)
- [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands)
- [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/command-line)

Please notice that you can't use these helpers in a regular script.
Depending on the libraries in use or the context of writing those identifiers, they may have a completely different meaning, compared to the builtin helpers since they can be assigned arbitrarily there.